# Android device running 2.3.6 not displaying in device list with API level 10 in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I've seen this question asked on here before, but nothing is working. I have a program set up with a minimum rep. of 2.3.3, a target of 2.3.3, AND a compile of 2.3.3. I hit "Run" and it just requests me to add an AVD. The emulators are terribly slow, so I'm forced to use my own device. I already have USB debugging enabled, I am also allowing apps from sources besides the Play Store. Anyone have a similar issue, or know how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you could clarify, do you mean that your device is plugged in but not showing up on the device list? Otherwise, what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Precisely. Lemme edit that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Edit: Check the launch config first, as it is easy to do and could save time if that is the issue)

I had a problem similar to this when I first started developing for Android. The solution I found was to make sure that all the drivers for your phone are installed to the computer. For example, for a Samsung GS3 you have to install Kies to get all the drivers. If you are certain you have them all already, try uninstalling and reinstalling them.

You also should check your launch configuration by going to Project > Properties then going to the Run/Debug Settings tab and editing whatever is there (there should only be one). Make sure the target of the config is set to "Always prompt top pick device".

Comment: I'm using an LG phone, what "drivers" may I need for that? I'm new to all of this, and am unfamiliar with most of it.

Comment: I would recommend first checking the launch config (Meant to put it first, will edit post) as it is easy. If it is setup properly, go to http://www.lg.com/ca_en/support/software-manuals and find your phone model. Once you do, go to the Software Update tab and download the USB driver.

Comment: Okay, me and my noob-y self is unsure of what a "launch config" is. Like I said, new to this entire thing. Could you explain?

Comment: A launch config essentially tells Eclipse how it should run the app once it is compiled. So, it says on what device the app will run and include various other parameters (someone else may have a more in-depth explanation than I; I only have some experience messing with them)

Comment: So, is that the entire "Target", "Minimum" and "Compile with" thing in the beggining?

Comment: From what I understand, no: The Minimum SDK option says what the lowest version of Android the app will run on is (ie. if you are using features added in later versions of Android that aren't in older ones and so won't work). The Target is what you are specifically writing it for (ie. if you are writing with KitKat in mind, then you would select 4.4). Finally, the Compile With setting determines what level of Android the compilier will use (from what I understand, this is almost always the same as Target SDK). Someone with more experience might have a better/more correct answer...

Comment: Okay, I installed it, is anything required otherwise? Like in the SDK manager?

Answer (score 0):

API 10 is 2.3.7-2.3.x (I think some vendors got up to .11 before honeycomb (API 11 3.0))), API 9 is 2.3-2.3.6

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels API 10 is 2.3.3+, not 2.3.7+

Comment: I guess I don't remember those dark times that well